# Prolog : Keep getting false result

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to create a program which can place the maximum of knight on a n * n chess without any knight eating the other. 
I managed to find how to do that, however I keep getting the false result instead of the display of the list where is the solution.

```
:- use_module(library(lists), [member/2]).
:- use_module(contestlib, [for/3]).

genere(0,[]).
genere(N,[N|L]) :-
   N>0,
   N1 is N-1,
   genere(N1,L).

generePos(N,[(Lig,Col)]) :-
   genere(N,L),
   member(Lig,L),
   member(Col,L).

genereEchiquier(N,PlacedKnights) :-
   findall((X,Y),(for(X,1,N),for(Y,1,N)),PlacedKnights).

knights(N) :-
    genereEchiquier(N,PlacedKnights),
    generePos(N,P1),
    knighta(P1,PlacedKnights).

knighta([(X,Y)|_],[]) :-
   write("No solution, next sol").
knighta([(X,Y)|_],[_|PlacedKnights]) :-
   (  is_attacked(X,Y,PlacedKnights)
   -> knights(P1,PlacedKnights)
   ;  write([(X,Y)|PlacedKnights)!
   ).

is_attacked(X,Y,PlacedKnights) :-
    ( NX is X - 1, NY is Y - 2
    ; NX is X - 1, NY is Y + 2
    ; NX is X + 1, NY is Y - 2
    ; NX is X + 1, NY is Y + 2
    ; NX is X - 2, NY is Y - 1
    ; NX is X - 2, NY is Y + 1
    ; NX is X + 2, NY is Y - 1
    ; NX is X + 2, NY is Y + 1
    ),
    member((NX,NY),PlacedKnights).
```

when I run the program in debug mode, the line `knighta(P1,PlacedKnights)`. doesn't take the program to `knighta/2` : here

```
knighta([(X,Y)|_],[_|PlacedKnights])
```

I have no idea why.

Comment: http://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/ppcbook/solutions/contestlib.pl

Comment: Do not change your answer back to the original state!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there are some problems with your code:

- first I would advice you to indent your code;
- you should use `]` instead of `!`;
- you sometimes call `knights` where it should be `knighta`; and
- you should first use `member` before the constraints in `is_attached`.

Perhaps you should consider a total redesign.

First of all, you could use the following as an `is_attacked` predicate:

```
is_attacked(X,Y,PlacedKnights) :-
    member((NX,NY),PlacedKnights),
    is_attacked(X,Y,NX,NY).

is_attacked(XA,YA,XB,YB) :-
    DX is abs(XA-XB),
    DY is abs(YA-YB),
    is_attacked(DX,DY).

is_attacked(1,2).
is_attacked(2,1).
```

You thus iterate over all already placed knights, and you calculate the difference and check if it is a `(2,1)` or `(1,2)` difference.

Next you could use the following predicate to generate all possible configurations:

```
generateSolution(R,_,R).
generateSolution(Q,N,R) :-
    for(X,1,N),
    for(Y,1,N),
    \+ member((X,Y),Q),
    \+ is_attacked(X,Y,Q),
    generateSolution([(X,Y)|Q],N,R).
```

Where `generateSolution(L,N,R)` is a predicate with `L` the already placed knights, `N` the size of the board and `R` any configuration with the already given knights that is correct (note this is not necessary the maximum number of knights).

But that's not that efficient: you don't perform *symmetry breaking* and thus generate a lot of duplicates:

```
?- generateSolution([],4,R),length(R,4).
R = [ (1, 4), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ; <- duplicate of
R = [ (2, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 1), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 3), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 4), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ; <- this one
R = [ (2, 1), (1, 4), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (3, 4), (1, 4), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 1), (1, 4), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 2), (1, 4), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 3), (1, 4), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 4), (1, 4), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (1, 4), (2, 1), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (3, 4), (2, 1), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
```

You can improve this by enforcing a constraint that says you can only increase the `(X,Y)` coordinates:

```
% Any solution is a solution.
generateSolution(R,_,R).
% If no knight is placed on the board, select one with arbitrary `X` and `Y`.
generateSolution([],N,R) :-
    for(X,1,N),
    for(Y,1,N),
    generateSolution([(X,Y)],N,R).
% If already placed one, fetch that solution, and propose a position (X,Y) with the same X and larger Y
generateSolution([(XL,YL)|T],N,R) :-
    YL1 is YL+1,
    for(Y,YL1,N),
    \+ is_attacked(XL,Y,[(XL,YL)|T]),
    generateSolution([(XL,Y),(XL,YL)|T],N,R).
% Or generate one with a larger X
generateSolution([(XL,YL)|T],N,R) :-
    XL1 is XL+1,
    for(X,XL1,N),
    for(Y,1,N),
    \+ is_attacked(X,Y,[(XL,YL)|T]),
    generateSolution([(X,Y),(XL,YL)|T],N,R).
```

Here, or `Y` must be larger than the previous `Y`, or `X` must be larger. The query thus no longer considers duplicates:

```
?- generateSolution([],4,R),length(R,4).
R = [ (1, 4), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (2, 1), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (2, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (3, 4), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 1), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 3), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 4), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (2, 1), (1, 4), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (2, 2), (1, 4), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (3, 4), (1, 4), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 1), (1, 4), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 2), (1, 4), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 3), (1, 4), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 4), (1, 4), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (3, 4), (2, 1), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 1), (2, 1), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 2), (2, 1), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 3), (2, 1), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 4), (2, 1), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (3, 4), (2, 2), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
R = [ (4, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2), (1, 1)] ;
```

Now in order to find the maximum number of knights, you can *bootstrap*:

```
bootstrap(N,Sol) :-
    once(bootstrap(N,[],0,Sol)).

bootstrap(N,_,I,S) :-
    once((generateSolution([],N,R),length(R,K),K > I)),
    !,
    bootstrap(N,R,K,S).
bootstrap(_,S,_,S).
```

The predicate works as follows: as first solution, you use `[]` (the empty list which always succeeds). Next you start searching for a configuration with more knights:

```
once((generateSolution([],N,R),length(R,K),K > I)),
```

Once such solution `R` with number of knights `K` is found, you take the new solution as the current solution, set the number of knights and start searching for a solution with more knights. If eventually that fails, you return the last current solution.

**EXAMPLE**:

```
?- bootstrap(1,S),write(S).
[ (1,1)]
S = [ (1, 1)].

?- bootstrap(2,S),write(S).
[ (2,2), (2,1), (1,2), (1,1)]
S = [ (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 2), (1, 1)].

?- bootstrap(3,S),write(S).
[ (3,3), (3,1), (2,2), (1,3), (1,1)]
S = [ (3, 3), (3, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3), (1, 1)].

?- bootstrap(4,S),write(S).
[ (4,4), (4,3), (4,2), (4,1), (1,4), (1,3), (1,2), (1,1)]
S = [ (4, 4), (4, 3), (4, 2), (4, 1), (1, 4), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1)].

?- bootstrap(5,S),write(S).
[ (5,5), (5,3), (5,1), (4,4), (4,2), (3,5), (3,3), (3,1), (2,4), (2,2), (1,5), (1,3), (1,1)]
S = [ (5, 5), (5, 3), (5, 1), (4, 4), (4, 2), (3, 5), (3, 3), (3, 1), (..., ...)|...].

?- bootstrap(6,S),write(S).
```

Full code:

```
bootstrap(N,Sol) :-
    once(bootstrap(N,[],0,Sol)).

bootstrap(N,_,I,S) :-
    once((generateSolution([],N,R),length(R,K),K > I)),
    !,
    bootstrap(N,R,K,S).
bootstrap(_,S,_,S).

generateSolution(R,_,R).
generateSolution([],N,R) :-
    for(X,1,N),
    for(Y,1,N),
    generateSolution([(X,Y)],N,R).
generateSolution([(XL,YL)|T],N,R) :-
    YL1 is YL+1,
    for(Y,YL1,N),
    \+ is_attacked(XL,Y,[(XL,YL)|T]),
    generateSolution([(XL,Y),(XL,YL)|T],N,R).
generateSolution([(XL,YL)|T],N,R) :-
    XL1 is XL+1,
    for(X,XL1,N),
    for(Y,1,N),
    \+ is_attacked(X,Y,[(XL,YL)|T]),
    generateSolution([(X,Y),(XL,YL)|T],N,R).

is_attacked(X,Y,PlacedKnights) :-
    member((NX,NY),PlacedKnights),
    is_attacked(X,Y,NX,NY).

is_attacked(XA,YA,XB,YB) :-
    DX is abs(XA-XB),
    DY is abs(YA-YB),
    is_attacked(DX,DY).

is_attacked(1,2).
is_attacked(2,1).
```

Note that more clever techniques exist, for instance much time is wasted validating whether a knight is attacked and there are additional symmetry breaking methods as well as ways to prevent returning a solution with a smaller number of knights with `generateSolution`. This is only a raw sketch.

---

**A non-backtracking optimal solution**

As you can notice, almost all results follow a pattern:

```
1:
+-+
|x|
+-+
2:
+-+-+
|x|x|
+-+-+
|x|x|
+-+-+
3:
+-+-+-+
|x| |x|
+-+-+-+
| |x| |
+-+-+-+
|x| |x|
+-+-+-+
4:
+-+-+-+-+
|x| |x| |
+-+-+-+-+
| |x| |x|
+-+-+-+-+
|x| |x| |
+-+-+-+-+
| |x| |x|
+-+-+-+-+
```

The pattern that occurs from the moment `N` is greater than or equal to `N` is that you place a knight on `(0,0)` and every `(i,i+2*j)` with `i` and `j` integers (`j` can be less than `0`). This is the guaranteed maximum.

You can thus generate this with:

```
solution(1,[(1,1)]).
solution(2,[(2,2),(2,1),(1,2),(1,1)]).
solution(N,L) :-
    N > 2,
    solution([],N,1,1,L).

solution(L,N,I,_,L) :-
    I > N,
    !.
solution(L,N,I,J,S) :-
    JN is J+2,
    JN =< N,
    !,
    solution([(I,J)|L],N,I,JN,S).
solution(L,N,I,J,S) :-
    IN is I+1,
    JN is (I mod 2)+1,
    IN =< N,
    !,
    solution([(I,J)|L],N,IN,JN,S).
solution(L,N,I,J,[(I,J)|L]).
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```
?- solution(20,L),write(L).
[ (20,20), (20,18), (20,16), (20,14), (20,12), (20,10), (20,8), (20,6), (20,4), (20,2), (19,19), (19,17), (19,15), (19,13), (19,11), (19,9), (19,7), (19,5), (19,3), (19,1), (18,20), (18,18), (18,16), (18,14), (18,12), (18,10), (18,8), (18,6), (18,4), (18,2), (17,19), (17,17), (17,15), (17,13), (17,11), (17,9), (17,7), (17,5), (17,3), (17,1), (16,20), (16,18), (16,16), (16,14), (16,12), (16,10), (16,8), (16,6), (16,4), (16,2), (15,19), (15,17), (15,15), (15,13), (15,11), (15,9), (15,7), (15,5), (15,3), (15,1), (14,20), (14,18), (14,16), (14,14), (14,12), (14,10), (14,8), (14,6), (14,4), (14,2), (13,19), (13,17), (13,15), (13,13), (13,11), (13,9), (13,7), (13,5), (13,3), (13,1), (12,20), (12,18), (12,16), (12,14), (12,12), (12,10), (12,8), (12,6), (12,4), (12,2), (11,19), (11,17), (11,15), (11,13), (11,11), (11,9), (11,7), (11,5), (11,3), (11,1), (10,20), (10,18), (10,16), (10,14), (10,12), (10,10), (10,8), (10,6), (10,4), (10,2), (9,19), (9,17), (9,15), (9,13), (9,11), (9,9), (9,7), (9,5), (9,3), (9,1), (8,20), (8,18), (8,16), (8,14), (8,12), (8,10), (8,8), (8,6), (8,4), (8,2), (7,19), (7,17), (7,15), (7,13), (7,11), (7,9), (7,7), (7,5), (7,3), (7,1), (6,20), (6,18), (6,16), (6,14), (6,12), (6,10), (6,8), (6,6), (6,4), (6,2), (5,19), (5,17), (5,15), (5,13), (5,11), (5,9), (5,7), (5,5), (5,3), (5,1), (4,20), (4,18), (4,16), (4,14), (4,12), (4,10), (4,8), (4,6), (4,4), (4,2), (3,19), (3,17), (3,15), (3,13), (3,11), (3,9), (3,7), (3,5), (3,3), (3,1), (2,20), (2,18), (2,16), (2,14), (2,12), (2,10), (2,8), (2,6), (2,4), (2,2), (1,19), (1,17), (1,15), (1,13), (1,11), (1,9), (1,7), (1,5), (1,3), (1,1)]
L = [ (20, 20), (20, 18), (20, 16), (20, 14), (20, 12), (20, 10), (20, 8), (20, 6), (..., ...)|...].
```

Or a graphical representation:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |x| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Comment: First thank you for taking the time to answer me . I tried replacing this in my code but it doesn't seems to change anything, When I launch the debugger, the problems seems to be here : knighta(P1,PlacedKnights). when prolog arrives here, he doesn't go to knighta([(X,Y)|_],[_|PlacedKnights]) , so it gives me the false error, here's a screen :http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/04/1421764324-error.jpg

Comment: @omar: I added a lot of additional problems. But I think you better first explain how your program works. What each predicate is supposed to do. Currently it's a bit of a chaotic...

Comment: Also in Prolog, `(,)/2` has priority over `(;)/2`! See for example: `?- write_canonical((a,b,c;d,e,f)).`, yielding: `;(','(a,','(b,c)),','(d,','(e,f)))`. Thus, this specific bracketing makes no difference.

Comment: Can't post everything in one comment so , k, here we go , the generePos(N,[N|L]) predicate generates all the position of a chessboard goes from [(1,1)] to [(n,n)]  . 
genereEchiquier(N,PlacedKnights) generates in a single List all the position of the chessboard [(1,1) , ...... (n,n))

Comment: is_attacked(X,Y,PlacedKnights) true if the knight on the X,Y position can be attacked by one of the Knight which is in the PlacedKnights List
knights(N) where N is the chessboard size, resolve the problem , in the begining, the PlacedKnights are everywhere ( they occupy all the chessboard) , and generePos try for each position
if the knight can be attacked by the other Knights if not, then we have solved the problem , so we display the solutions, else we remove one Knight from the PlacedKnights List and try again the same processus

Comment: @omar1995: updated with full algorithm and explanation.

Comment: @omar1995: added some comment.

Comment: @CommuSoft Sorry for bothering you, I already learned lot of thing in prolog thanks to your help, my question might be stupid but what does the operator \+ mean? I just began prolog and I didn't find in the net it signification , is it like a "if" ? ( ->)?

Comment: `\+` is negation as finite failure. Semantically it is a bit equivalent with the `!` (not) operator in Java. Although it works differently. I also provided a fast (non-backtracking solution to the problem).