# Compare two solution in a prolog call

Tags: prolog

I write prolog program as below. Now, when I run halfsister predicate as `halfsister(X,Y)`. I got result

```
X = ann
Y = sylvia ? ;

X = sylvia
Y = ann ? ;
```

but both are the same result but showing twice. How can I make the program to show the same result for once only?
my prolog code:

```
parent(john,ann).
parent(jim,john).
parent(jim,keith).
parent(mary,ann).
parent(mary,sylvia).
parent(brian,sylvia).
male(keith).
male(jim).
male(brian).
female(sylvia).
female(ann).
female(marry).
female(john).
brother(X,Y):-parent(Z,X),parent(Z,Y),male(X),X\==Y.
uncle(X,Y):-brother(X,Z),parent(Z,Y).
halfsister(X,Y):-
    parent(A,X),
    parent(A,Y),
    parent(B,X),
    parent(C,Y),
    \+(A = B),
    \+(A = C),
    \+(B = C),
    female(Y).
```

Thanks for your valuable, time.

Comment: Can wrap in https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=distinct/1

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm not still getting how to use it in my code section. I'm learning Prolog.

Comment: Oops, the X and Y values are switching around, rather than being shown twice, so distinct won't help. Instead, add e.g. a final condition "X @> Y" to the end of halfsister/2, for symmetry-breaking as explained at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28047637/prolog-keep-getting-false-result

Comment: It is much safer to use "dif(A, B)" instead of "\+(A = B)", to be reliable with non-ground variables, as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757261/using-2-or-dif-2

Comment: "both are the same result" - No, they are not the same result.

Comment: Actually, I think a better answer than my earlier comments is to say that the "duplicate" answer given by Prolog in the OP is correct as-is, because X and Y are different people. As mentioned, can use @> or @< to break symmetry when appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I don't think it is necessary to eliminate this "duplication", because the predicate `halfsister(X,Y)` means "Y is X's half sister". You got two answers, one means "sylvia is ann's half-sister", the other means "ann is sylvia's half-sister". So there is nothing wrong here.
2. If you insist on eliminating them, you can try:

   ```
   halfsister(X,Y):-
       parent(A,X),
       parent(A,Y),
       parent(B,X),
       parent(C,Y),
       \+(A = B),
       \+(A = C),
       \+(B = C),
       female(Y),
       (   female(X)
       ->  X @< Y
       ;   true
       ).
   ```

   Query:

   ```
   ?- halfsister(X,Y).
   X = ann,
   Y = sylvia ;
   false.
   ```

Comment: There is no advantage to using -> ( https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=-%3E/2 ) here.

Comment: @brebs I used `->` because it may be exist `male`. For example, adding facts `parent(mary,zed). parent(john,zed). male(zed).` If do not use `(female(X) ->  X @< Y ; true)`,  the `X = zed, Y = sylvia` will not be in the answers.

Comment: I agree that using `->` is usually not a good idea.

Comment: "X @> Y" is sufficient, for symmetry-breaking. Adding -> just risks breaking soundness.

Comment: @brebs Try to add facts `parent(mary,aaron). parent(john,aaron). male(aaron).`. Then do the query `?- halfsister(X,Y).`, aaron won't be in the answers if only using `X @> Y`. However, sylvia is apparently aaron's half sister.

Comment: You're contorting the logic with "female(X) ->  X @< Y; true" to become unreliable due to the "; true" alternative.

Comment: @brebs What's the problem, can you give an example?

Comment: As an example (this will probably show with awful formatting) of how the "; true" alternative affects:  ?- member(A, [1, 2, 3]), (A > 2 -> A > 1 ; true).
A = 1 ;
A = 2 ;
A = 3.

Comment: @brebs I don't understand what you mean. What I mean is that (1) what's the problem of using `->` in this family example? (2) as we know that Prolog is a pragmatic programming language, it is not necessary to keep all predicates logic pure as long as it get our jobs done. Here I just treat X and Y as two output variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242727/discussion-between-brebs-and-chansey).

Comment: After a great discussion, the purpose of the -> here is to remove the symmetry when both X and Y are half-sisters of each other. Could be perhaps more intuitively expressed as: (male(X) -> true ; X <@ Y).